# How to convert multidimensional array to List<List<double>>?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to convert a `double[,]` to a `List<List<double>>` what is the best possible way of doing this performance wise.

Comment: How important is this performance to you? Is this conversion really the bottleneck in your application?

Comment: _"what is the best possible way of doing this performance wise"_ - Without appropriate evidence, this is just going to result in a mass of opinionated answers with no performance data.  **Subject to opinion**

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What were your performance metrics? How did your measurements compare to your goal?  Show some effort here if you want help.

Comment: This is by no means the bottleneck in my application, due to the powers at be there are several "area's of interest" and with a static array the List<List<double> is just nonsense for my application. Just looking at any options to improve performance where I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is *O(n)* solution of conversion. I don't think there are algorithms which work faster than *O(n)*.

```
public static List<List<double>> ConvertToListOfLists(double[,] array)
{
    List<List<double>> result = new List<List<double>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        List<double> row = new List<double>();
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            row.Add(array[i, j]);
        }
        result.Add(row);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Probably would be nice for you to explain why this is the _"best possible way of doing this performance wise."_

Answer (score 1):

2D arrays are not so handy as jagged ones, you can try something like this:

```
  double[,] source = ...

  List<List<double>> result = new List<List<double>>(source.GetLength(0));

  for (int i = 0; i < source.GetLength(0); ++i) {
    List<double> line = new List<double>(source.GetLength(1));

    result.Add(line);

    for (int j = 0; j < source.GetLength(1); ++j)
      line.Add(source[i, j]);
  }
```

The code above assumes that `source` is a usual *zero-based* array; in very rare (almost paranoic) case of *arbitrary based* array (see [Array.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x836773a(v=vs.110).aspx) for details if you want to create such an array):

```
  double[,] source = ...

  List<List<double>> result = new List<List<double>>(source.GetLength(0));

  // please, notice <= comparison
  for (int i = source.GetLowerBound(0); i <= source.GetUpperBound(0); ++i) {
    List<double> line = new List<double>(source.GetLength(1));

    result.Add(line);

    // please, notice <= comparison
    for (int j = source.GetLowerBound(1); j <= source.GetUpperBound(1); ++j)
      line.Add(source[i, j]);
  }
```

Compare this code with terse but readable one for *jagged* array:

```
  double[][] source = ... 

  List<List<double>> result = source
    .Select(line => line.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

That's why we often avoid 2D array using.

Comment: This answer might be nearly the same as the other answer, but notice the use of the `List` constructor that takes an initial capacity - a performance gain that doesn't really impact readability.